# WinDivert - need to encrypt and decrypt network packets

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, encryption

I need to encrypt and decrypt all network packets between two computers. For example using WinDivert we can capture, modify and reinject packets. I see only two ways:

1. WAY: capture an outbound packet, encrypt **payload** and reinject the packet --> capture an inbound packet, decrypt **payload** and reinject the packet.
2. WAY: capture an outbound packet, encrypt **packet** and send it through an socket --> receive it through socket, decrypt **packet** and reinject it.

I'm not sure about their feasibility.

- Is it possible to encrypt a payload?
- How can I send a WinDivert packet through socket?

It will be really helpful if you have any suggestion or example.

Comment: Sounds like you need VPN between the computers. Unless you plan to code one yourself, you might get better answers asking this in [sf].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encryption is non-trivial. This is potentially a very complicated project, depending on exactly you have in mind.

In terms of packet capture and re-injection, both "WAY"s are feasible.  WAY 1. is a good idea if you are not interested in encrypting the IP header, whereas WAY 2. is useful if you want to encrypt the entire packet.

For WAY 2., you need to be careful not to create a loop.  E.g. WinDivert re-captures the encrypted packet.  This depends what your filter string is.

For both WAY 1. and 2., another problem is that encryption typically increases the size of the packet.  For WAY 2., you also are adding a IP/UDP header, further increasing the size.  The problem is that the original captured packet may already be the max MTU size, so the size cannot be increased.  The solutions are non-trivial, either packet fragmentation or injecting PMTU ICMP messages.

I'm not sure I understand your specific questions: WinDivert captures packets into a buffer, and you can do whatever you like to this buffer.  This includes encrypting it (using whatever method), re-injecting it, or sending it to a socket, etc.